# Inheritance in Ruby Classes

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm learning about ruby classes and inheritance. I'm just practicing by making random classes and objects that inherit methods from the class.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to change one of the inherited properties? For example, each object here is inheriting a "slogan" method. How would I write the method if I wanted to be able to change the slogan from what was inherited?

```
class Person

  attr_reader :age
  attr_accessor :slogan

  def initialize
    @age = 0
  end

  def get_older
    @age = @age += 1
  end
end

class Student < Person
  def slogan
    "Ruby is cool"
  end
end

class Musician < Person
  def slogan
    "Music is cool"
  end
end

mickey = Student.new
# p mickey.class
# p Student.superclass
p mickey.age
mickey.get_older
p mickey.age
p mickey.slogan

sarah = Musician.new
# p mickey.class
# p Student.superclass
p sarah.age
sarah.get_older
p sarah.age
p sarah.slogan
```

Comment: You already have so I am not sure what the question is `Person.new.slogan #=> nil`, `Student.new.slogan #=> "Ruby is cool"`, and `Musician.new.slogan #=> "Music is cool"`

Answer (score 1):

If you intend that `slogan` be modifiable, then make it an accessor.

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :slogan
end

mickey = Person.new
mickey.slogan = "Yo"
puts mickey.slogan
```

We can even have a default value

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :slogan

  def initialize
    self.slogan = "Hello, kind friend :)"
  end
end
```

Note that `attr_accessor`, behind the scenes, is defining two methods `slogan` and `slogan=` which access an instance variable. So the class I just wrote above is equivalent to

```
class Person

  def initialize
    self.slogan = "Hello, kind friend :)"
  end

  def slogan
    @slogan
  end

  def slogan=(value)
    @slogan = value
  end

end
```

Comment: Understood, this is super helpful, thanks so much!